# How to query for 'task' records by date

Tags: ios, sqlite, select

We are trying to make a app that keeps a users schedule. He wants a simple tableview to display a different section for each day and he wants all the tasks for that day to display in order. Here is the db schema im using:

```
TASK_ID , TASK_NAME(STRING), TASK_DURRATION(AMOUNT OF TIME IN MILI), TASK_START_TSTAMP(EPOCH TIMESTAMP), TASK_END_TSTAMP(EPOCH TIMESTAMP),  TASK_COMPLETED(BOOL)
```

How would I begin to go about querying for tasks by day? Like if i wanted to return all the tasks for the next 7 days.

I have to :

•Allow users to create tasks  with a specific duration and in some cases a specific start time 
•Query for the next 7 days worth of tasks chunked by date.

So what do I do? Find a way to get a array of the next 7 days, loop through and run a query for each one for all the tasks scheduled on that day?

[image]

Comment: That's not a schema. That's a list of column names.

Comment: Its: a representation of a plan or theory in the form of an outline or model.

aka the definition of schema, but thank you for the unhelpful answer and unnecessary down vote.

Comment: My point is, how can people help when you don't tell us any useful details? It's hard to offer suggestions on doing a query without evening know the minimum basics like data types or sample data or desired results. Your question was down voted because it lacks any sufficient details. It also shows no effort on your part.

Comment: Im new to sqlite, i thought the whole idea was there are not data types. I dont know how to give you these details....I need to select all tasks scheduled in the next 7 days and have them chunked by date. I have no idea where to even begin. Sounded alot easier when I was giving him a estimate.

Comment: I am just starting this project so I guess thats up for suggestion. I kind of feel paralyzed  at the moment, which is why I asked the best I could. I made some updates to the schema in my op, but nothing HAS to be that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to calculate `startDate` and `endDate` to be used in your SQL using calendrical calculations of `NSCalendar`.

Let's say it's 3:24pm on January 20th, and you want all tasks in the next seven days, up to 3:24pm on January 27th, you could do something like:

```
let startDate = NSDate()
let endDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 7, toDate: startDate, options: [])!
```

Then build your query using those start and end dates.

If, however, you want all events scheduled anytime on January 20th through January 26th (inclusive), you could use something like:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: NSDate())
let startDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
let endDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 7, toDate: startDate, options: [])!
```

Then you could build your SQL using `startDate` and `endDate`, if you're storing those as UNIX epoch double values:

```
let sql = "select * from TASKS where TASK_START_TSTAMP >= \(startDate.timeIntervalSince1970) and TASK_START_TSTAMP < \(endDate.timeIntervalSince1970)"
```

Comment: Alright this at least gives me some clues in the right directions to research, but this NSCalendar, is this connected to the apple calendar app on your phone? <br>

 if so is using it going to make my life easier/make this faster or probably add more work bc hes only paying for a very bare bones MVP.

Comment: Correct, this uses the `NSCalendar` class which is part of Cocoa Touch. Note, I updated answer to show sample SQL to retrieve based timestamps stored in "unixepoch" numeric values.

Comment: So the end goal here is this:http://imgur.com/JnaVu97


It basically displays the next 7 days of scheduled tasks in a tableview in order, each date is in its own section of a tableview and tasks that do not have a specific start time have to be "fitted" into the schedule automatically.


Would you recommend querying for all scheduled tasks in the next 7 days and then looping through them to add data regarding what tasks should go under which section or would you recommend doing 7 queries ( one for each date)

Comment: For performance reasons, I'd personally be inclined do one query and build my model from as I step through the results. But either approach would work fine. The difference will probably not be observable.